# Find the Radius of circle, given arc length and total change in height

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line, arc-length

Here is a picture of my problem: [image]

"m" (not sure if there is a name for this) is known and the arc length between D and B is known. BC is tangent to the circle at point B. What is the radius "r" (or chord length BD or angle BAD)?

I can work this out graphical for m = 2.1m and arc length BD = 5m but I don't have a formula for it yet.

Sorry, first time poster and on the site... I came across this problem at work and I have been unable to solve it as my algebra is rusty an my Googlefoo failed me. I looked through about 40 related questions on this site and didn't find the answer, but it looks like there are lots of Mathematicians here which should be able to solve it.

Any help or a link to the right page would be great, Cheers!

Comment: Hint: let $\theta = \widehat{BAD}$ (in radians), then the arc length of $BD$ is $r \cdot \theta$, and $m + r \cdot cos \theta = r$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, so simple! How to I up vote or say problem solved?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. If you post an answer in more detail, then you can accept your own answer (which won't bring you rep points, but will indicate that the problem was solved).

Comment: I never solved this one properly, is there are good algebraic solution?
My answer was BD=r cos^-1((r-m)/r) solve for r...

Comment: That's about as far as you can go. The resulting equation is transcendental, and there are no "nice" closed form solutions, so it will have to be solved numerically.